# /usr/bin/env ruby no such file or directory: Using capistrano 3, capistrano/rbenv, capistrano/bundler and capistrano/rails (using rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'm using capistrano, capistrano/rbenv, capistrano/bundler and capistrano/rails. I get this error in the step where capistrano compiles the assets:

```
DEBUG [49a50df6]    /usr/bin/env:
DEBUG [49a50df6]    ruby
DEBUG [49a50df6]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [49a50df6]
```

In the production server `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` is correct.
I'm aware of this: [why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/)
But I can't get it to work.

This is my `Capfile`:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/assets
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails/tree/master/migrations
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

This is my `deploy.rb`:

```
# rbenv
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.0.0-p247'

# bundler
set :bundle_gemfile, -> { release_path.join('Gemfile') }
set :bundle_dir, -> { shared_path.join('bundle') }
set :bundle_flags, '--deployment --quiet'
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')
set :bundle_binstubs, -> { shared_path.join('bin') }
set :bundle_roles, :all

# rails
set :rails_env, 'production'

set :application, 'MY APP'
set :repo_url, 'MY_REPO.git'

# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

# set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app'
# set :scm, :git

# set :format, :pretty
# set :log_level, :debug
# set :pty, true

set :linked_files, %w{.env config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

And this is my `staging.rb`:

```
set :stage, :staging

# Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary
# server in each group is considered to be the first
# unless any hosts have the primary property set.
#role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
#role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}
#role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}

# Extended Server Syntax
# ======================
# This can be used to drop a more detailed server
# definition into the server list. The second argument
# something that quacks like a has can be used to set
# extended properties on the server.
#server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value
server 'my_server', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{web app db}

# you can set custom ssh options
# it's possible to pass any option but you need to keep in mind that net/ssh understand limited list of options
# you can see them in [net/ssh documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start)
# set it globally
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
# and/or per server
# server 'example.com',
#   user: 'user_name',
# roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user_name', # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: 'please use keys'
#   }
# setting per server overrides global ssh_options

# fetch(:default_env).merge!(rails_env: :staging)

set :deploy_to, '/home/my_user'
```

And this is the full trace:

```
 INFO [c24b8f94] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p247 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile on 162.243.16.201
DEBUG [c24b8f94] Command: cd /home/my_app/releases/20131101193513 && ( RAILS_ENV=production RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p247 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [c24b8f94]    /usr/bin/env:
DEBUG [c24b8f94]    ruby
DEBUG [c24b8f94]    : No such file or directory
DEBUG [c24b8f94]
cap aborted!
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:61:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:89:in `with'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:60:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/assets.rake:59:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/patricio/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
```

By the way, I think it's not related to `$PATH`, because `bundle install` runs just fine.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide your ```Capfile```, ```deploy.rb```, ```production/staging.rb```?

Comment: Could you provide the full error trace, please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, fixed it.

I added this:

```
set :default_env, { path: "~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }
```

to my `deploy.rb`.

I'm not sure is the best solution, but it worked.

Comment: Yep, modifying PATH in Capistrano. is quite dirty hack.
It's failing on `cd /home/my_app/releases/20131101193513 && ( RAILS_ENV=production RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0-p247 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )`

Did you try to run the same command manually?

Comment: Yes, I tried to run it manually and it worked. I'm about to create a PR in github.

Comment: What's your server OS?

Comment: @Kir I have the same issue. Deploying to Ubuntu 10.04. This suggested solution doesn't work for me, but manually I can do it.

Comment: We updated capistrano-rbenv recently and you can try it with the latest Capistrano. Does it work for you?

Comment: This works for rvm too: `set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }`

Answer (score 52):

Okay, as I had the same issue and it took me quite a while to resolve it:

You are probably wondering why this command is not working while it IS working when you log into with you shell using ssh.

I am not an expert (so correct me when I am wrong): The thing is there are several differences in logging in on a remote server using ssh. 
To quote the documentation of capistrano:

> It's really a question of which kind of shell Capistrano is using,
>   it's a matrix of possibilities concerning login, non-login,
>   interactive, or non-interactive.

They have a fancy graphic [here](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/) (at the bottom) where they illustrate the path of files that are executed in login process. - *the given source is also interesting if you want to continue reading on this topic.*

**What is going wrong?**

When YOU log in using ssh you are (on login) executing several files (for example .bash_profile when you using the bash). Commonly your $PATH variable is extended with several paths to important functions in your envirement. BUT different login "styles" include different files.

As the documentation says again:

> By default Capistrano always assigns a non-login, non-interactive
>   shell.

In my case this lead to a case where my login file .bash_profile is not included BUT it included the settings for my rvm. The result that the capistrano login session didnt know about my rvm path.

**How can I fix this?**

For me it turned out to just be the *uncommenting* of the *require 'capistrano/rvm'* (As I am using RVM) line in the **Capfile** (located in the root of your rails-project.

**Hope to help someone.**

EDIT:

And for sure include `gem 'capistrano-rvm'` in the Gemfile!

Comment: +1 This fixed it for me. Great, detailed response. Way less arbitrary than adding paths to `deploy.rb`!

Comment: +1 man, both uncommenting the require 'capistrano/rvm' and adding the gem 'capistrano-rvm' to gemfile, did the magic for me!

Comment: This was very helpful, but I also had to install rvm and ruby on my server. That may have been obvious to others, but for the sake of completeness I add this detail. Thanks for the tip. This worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

I think you should execute

```
apt-get install git-core
```

at your server

Comment: How did you know to add git-core? Or what gave it away?

Comment: That package is already installed on my server, but I still have the above described issue. I don't understand the amount of upvote for this answer ! ️

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem using rbenv.  What solved it for me was including the rbenv library before bundler--not after it.  The order turned out to be important.  Here's what's in my Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```

If you did it right you should see the bundle command executed with the rbenv prefix, along these lines:

```
XX RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.3.0 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are requiring all of these gems in your Capfile.

Comment: And I required them in the `Capfile` as well.

Comment: @Kir This could be a comment on the question, instead of an answer

Answer (score 2):

Solution to ERROR:

> /usr/bin/env git no such file or directory capistrano

Install git in remote server, machine to which deployment is to be done.

```
apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem is:

```
DEBUG [3132b2c2]    /usr/bin/env: ‘bundle’: No such file or directory
DEBUG [3132b2c2]
```

I solved it this way:

In Debian, there is a block of code in your ~/.bashrc that says:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything

case $- in
   *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
esac
```

When you run Capistrano, it will actually use your ~/.bashrc but it will not run any command below that block of code.

So, I fixed the problem adding the lines of code that were required by load ruby environment above that block of code, so Capistrano could load bundle.

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/share/chruby/auto.sh
```

PS：I use chruby in my server.

Answer (score 0):

When I typed `bundle install` interactively on a Terminal, it worked. Now, when I use it through Capistrano, it doesn't work.

**I solved it this way:**

In Ubuntu, there is a block of code in your `~/.bashrc` that says:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
   *i*) ;;
     *) return;;
esac
```

When you run Capistrano, it will actually use your `~/.bashrc` **but it will not** run any command below that block of code.

So, I fixed the problem moving the lines of code that were required by `bundle install` **above** that block of code, so Capistrano could load them.

You could get a hint of which lines to move by running `which bundle`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error.After trying hard to resolve it, i remembered that i have removed few packages randomly from my server where i was deploying the code.

So i also removed git accidently.Running `sudo apt-get install git` fixed it .