# capistrano deploy fails on starting sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, sidekiq

My deploy goes good until the `sidekiq:start`:

```
00:18 sidekiq:start
      01 sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment production --logfile /home/user/cap/shared/log/sidekiq.log --concurrency 4 --daemon
      01 /usr/bin/env: sidekiq: No such file or directory
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as user@app.domain.com: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: /usr/bin/env: sidekiq: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: /usr/bin/env: sidekiq: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => sidekiq:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as user@app.domain.com: sidekiq exit status: 127
sidekiq stdout: Nothing written
sidekiq stderr: /usr/bin/env: sidekiq: No such file or directory

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:

 DEBUG [c0e43b64] Command: if test ! -d /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [c0e43b64] Finished in 0.079 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [2c3323b9] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ] as user@app.domain.com
 DEBUG [2c3323b9] Command: cd /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" ; /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ] )
 DEBUG [2c3323b9] Finished in 0.083 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [6813e38f] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112 /home/user/cap/releases/current as user@app.domain.com
 DEBUG [6813e38f] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112 /home/user/cap/releases/current )
  INFO [6813e38f] Finished in 0.080 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [6d1d7708] Running /usr/bin/env mv /home/user/cap/releases/current /home/user/cap as user@app.domain.com
 DEBUG [6d1d7708] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" ; /usr/bin/env mv /home/user/cap/releases/current /home/user/cap )
  INFO [6d1d7708] Finished in 0.080 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [0dbc1637] Running if test ! -d /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112'" 1>&2; false; fi as user@portal.nordcloud…
 DEBUG [0dbc1637] Command: if test ! -d /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [0dbc1637] Finished in 0.079 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [6b62769e] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ] as user@app.domain.com
 DEBUG [6b62769e] Command: cd /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" ; /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ] )
 DEBUG [6b62769e] Finished in 0.081 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
  INFO [eaed2dfc] Running /usr/bin/env sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid --environment production --logfile /home/user/cap/shared/log/sidekiq.log --concurrency …
 DEBUG [eaed2dfc] Command: cd /home/user/cap/releases/20160629062112 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.0" ; /usr/bin/env sidekiq --index 0 --pidfile /home/user/cap/shared/tmp/p…
 DEBUG [eaed2dfc]   /usr/bin/env: sidekiq: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have hints what's going on, what is it looking for in `/usr/bin/env` and mail question: how do I solve it?

Comment: this might help you  check the ruby file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716131/usr-bin-env-ruby-no-such-file-or-directory-using-capistrano-3-capistrano-rben

Comment: there may be some file use /usr/bin/env: sidekiq so it `#!/usr/bin/env sidekiq` ?

Comment: @RajarshiDas hey, thanks for link! But did not find the solution there..

Comment: Capistrano make an attempt to run exucutable file through `env` with name sidekiq. Create that file and add path to it to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you use rbenv. Do you also have the Capistrano support gem included?

https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv

Also, take a look into [this bug report](http://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/147) - might be helpful!

Comment: Have you already seen this bug report? https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq/issues/147

Comment: cool! the bugreport did it for capistrano-sidekiq! but deploy now fails on capistrano-sidekiq/monit - do you know maybe why?

Comment: Without knowing the error, I can only only say that I had to modify :sidekiq_monit_conf_dir to match the path for Monit in my Fedora Installation.

Comment: Does the folder /etc/monit/conf.d exist? That's the path I had to adjust